# Laravel 4.2 css files

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have project that was built on laravel 4.2. It was built by some other developer but since he has left it is given to me to maintain.

Problem is when I run project it does't load assets which I mean css/js and logo and images for page. In project he has used controller to get all asset files but I have no clue why that is creating a problem.

In head.blade.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/lib-head"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/errors"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/apps/main"></script>
```

In routes.php.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'assets'), function(){
  Route::get('js/lib-head', array(
    'uses'    => 'AssetsController@getJstHead',
    'as'      => 'assets.getJavascriptHead'
  ));
  Route::get('js/lib-body', array(
    'uses'    => 'AssetsController@getJavascriptBody',
    'as'      => 'assets.getJavascriptBody'
  ));
  Route::get('js/errors', array(
    'uses'    => 'AssetsController@getJavascriptErrors',
    'as'      => 'assets.getJavascriptErrors'
  ));
  Route::get('js/apps/{build}', array(
    'uses'    => 'AssetsController@getJavascriptApps',
    'as'      => 'assets.getJavascriptApps'
  ));
  Route::get('css/main', array(
    'uses'    => 'AssetsController@getCSSStandard',
    'as'      => 'assets.getCSSStandard'
  ));
});
```

And inside AssetController here is what code looks like.

```
 function getJavascriptApps($build = 'main') {

    //  Pull directory contents using Assetic
    $base = app_path().'/assets';
    $js = new AssetCollection(array(
      new FileAsset($base.'/js/util/_functions.js'),
      new FileAsset($base.'/js/util/_compilerfunctions.js'),
      new FileAsset($base.'/js/util/MyClass.class.js'),
      new FileAsset($base.'/js/util/_init.js'),
      new GlobAsset($base.'/js/apps/*')
    ));
    $contents = $js->dump();

    //  Return response with 200 status
    $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    return $response;

  }
```

I checked using browser network tool and response is 404 not found.

So my question is what am I doing wrong. I should mention this is only happening on ubuntu as for windows project runs smoothly only if contents of public folder are cut and paste inside htdocs and rest of the folder structure placed inside main xampp folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your local server can of course load sass. By the way sass like css is rendered by the brwoser, So you should not have problem with running your project.  just link the sass file the same way u link css with .sass

Comment: Yes but I don't see any main.sass file in specified location and its loading up at all. So I don't really know what is wrong with this project.

Comment: talk to the previous dev or see how the vmware instance is working.. Can't understand how we could be of "any help"

Comment: I would love to but he doesn't work in company anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your css from folder to page like this

```
   <link href="{{URL::to('/assets/css/main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I know how to link to asset file but loading an asset with controller totally new to me.